# Is There a Standard Algorithm to Iterate Over a Range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, range, standard-library

I need to call a lambda with every `int` in a range. Is there a standard algorithm that does this?

Ideally something equivalent:

```
for(auto i = 13; i < 42; ++i)[](int i){/*do something*/}(i);
```

Comment: Is using Boost an option?

Comment: @Praetorian I mean that could be a solution. I was hoping there was something in the C++ standard though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's possible the OP is looking for a solution that doesn't require storing a copy of the entire range.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you talking about [this `for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each)? I don't see how that works on a range of `int`s?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Oh, right. Sorry

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In that case, yes, I did search at all. I was hoping for something that is in the C++ standard though, not Boost.

Comment: With any luck, ranges will make it into the standard soon, and then the range of numbers would be represented by something like `view::iota(13, 41)`

Comment: @chris If you have a Technical Specification you can reference, I would like to accept this answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee, This is the best I've got, but I'm not sure whether there are plans to change it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html. Anyway, as an answer, I wouldn't count on it being the most useful until the TS is adopted or near that point.

Comment: @chris That's amazing, I'll scribble an answer up from that on Monday if you don't feel like taking the time to formalize it sometime before then.

Comment: @JonathanMee, If this interests you, there is more information on Eric Niebler's site. The ranges content seems to really start going around [November, 2013](http://ericniebler.com/2013/11/).

Comment: @chris I've finally finished reading the proposal and added an answer. Please feel free to comment/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned if Boost is an option there is a better way to do this. If not, the best way is in the original question:

```
for(auto i = 13; i < 42; ++i)[](int i){/*do something*/}(i);
```

However, the future is bright, [chris has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788512/is-there-a-standard-algorithm-to-iterate-over-a-range#comment45853682_28788512) proposal [N4128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html) which is suggesting incorporating ranges into the standard alongside iterators.

Now the draft is still in an early state, so there's a lot of clarification that is needed before how this will be used is nailed down. But one of the concepts is that all the STL algorithms would be overloaded to take `view`s which is a thin wrapper providing access to the contained elements, but also an intelligent end position.

Although a more complex example, chosen to showcase the power of `view`, the author's example in [Motivation and Scope](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#motivation-and-scope) uses `iota`, which is exactly what we want:

```
int total = accumulate(view::iota(1) |
                       view::transform([](int x){return x*x;}) |
                       view::take(10), 0);
```

For our purposes we'd need to use `generate_n` in a `for_each` algorithm:

```
for_each(view::generate_n(28,[]{static int i = 13; return i++;}),[](int i){/*do something*/});
```

This would cause `generate_n` to be called 28 times (13 + 28 = 41), the created `view` would provide iteration over these numbers, feeding them into our original lambda in the `for_each`.

[chris has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788512/is-there-a-standard-algorithm-to-iterate-over-a-range#comment45853682_28788512) that instead of `generate_n` a modification of `iota` might do the trick: `iota(13, 41)` It is key to note that whatever is used must have an end condition, because view *lazily* calls the generator, until no more items are requested. So this <strike>`for_each(view::iota(10), [](int i){/*do something*/});`</strike> defines an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in, no.

You can do it yourself with a hand-crafted iterator and [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), or use [Boost's counting iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) to help you along:

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::for_each(
        boost::counting_iterator<int>(13),
        boost::counting_iterator<int>(42),
        [](int i){ std::cout << i << ' '; }
    );
}
```

Output:

> 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc4e04f3c6be2d0c))

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of anything in the standard library that can produce a range of numbers on demand like you're asking for. But this can be done a couple of different ways using Boost.

1. Use Boost.Range to generate an integer range and use it with the range version of `for_each`

   ```
   boost::for_each(boost::irange(13, 42), [](int i){ std::cout << i << ' '; });
   ```
2. Use `boost::counting_iterator` from Boost.Iterator and pass those to `std::for_each`

   ```
   std::for_each(boost::make_counting_iterator(13),
                 boost::make_counting_iterator(42), 
                 [](int i){ std::cout << i << ' '; });
   ```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a693959e44ef522)